# How to read file in /WEB-INF/, but not in classes folder by using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver within SpringMVC?

Tags: spring

Spring: 3.2.0.RELEASE

The file i intended to read is placed at `/WEB-INF/resources/test.dat`.

Code as below:

```
 @javax.annotation.Resource(name = "pathMatchingResourcePatternResolver")
 private PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver;
 ...
 ...
 Resource resource2 = resolver.getResource("/WEB-INF/resources/test.dat");
    try {
        File file = resource2.getFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

From doc of PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver, it described: `and simple unprefixed paths such as "/WEB-INF/context.xml".`

But actually it cause an error that : `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/test.dat] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`.

Does anyone know what the problem is?!

Comment: verify whether the file is in read Only/archive mode.

Comment: Try to access using classpath by placing the file in classpath directory

Comment: I mean, what if this file has to be placed at /WEB-INF/resource folder? Do you have a way to do that by using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's a maven project. Instead of having this file in /WEB-INF/resource folder, put it into /src/main/resources folder. Resources in this folder are added to classpath. 
So you can use something like  :

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.dat");
```

This will work.

Comment: Correct as you said. But, what if this file has to be placed at /WEB-INF/resource folder, what should i do by using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver? I mean, according to doc of this resolver, it should works to read file in /WEB-INF/ folder?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and found the problem. The issue is that by defaul [`PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) uses [`DefaultResourceLoader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html) to actualy load resources. `DefaultResourceLoader` assumes that resources come from classpath, and it cannot handle web app. To fix that, you need to set another [`ResourceLoader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) implementation (like [`ServletContextResourceLoader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextResourceLoader.html)). But, IMHO, it's better to use [`ApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) to load resource (yeah, it can do it!). Just @Autowire it or implement [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html).